# Finding the nearest vertices that form the triangle to the objects position?

Tags: opengl, 3d, game-physics, physics-engine

I am currently trying to implement a physics system in my 3D OpenGL (LWJGL 3) game on the means of something like this: [image]

I want to calculate vector FN, for which I need a normal vector of a plane as seen in the image. I realised that the triangles that OpenGL uses to render, can be substituted for the plane. Obviously, I need the three vertices (for example, **m1, m2, m3** from the image above) forming the triangle that the **object is currently on**. My question is how do I get the three vertices form the triangle (plane) that the object is currently on?

Here are the resources that I currently have:

- The objects position in world space coordinated (x, y ,z)
- A mesh class containing the **ordered** vertex data of the terrain as well as the indices data.

Looping through the massive vertex data does not seem efficient per frame. How would I continue from here?

**EDIT**:

To be direct I want to find the nearest three vertices of the terrain to the position of the object.

Comment: @Kai Burjack  What I am after is to find the nearest three vertices (which creates the triangle) to the position of the object. I understand that OpenGL is graphical API; I am just trying to use the terrain vertices, to get an idea of the surface and its elevation of the object, so that I can calculate the normal.

Comment: @Kai Burjack But that would still lead to many calls per frame, would it still be considered efficient though?